# How to import a facebook post's comments?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I have tried using the code in [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) but it's not working when I try getting my post's comments. Anyone have tried this recently? *I read in some forums that the code they used may be outdated, and when I tried it, it didn't solve my problem*

I have tried two codes:

Code 1:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/cielomuyot/posts/903985589615702" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code 2:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}">

</head>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
</script>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<fb:comments href="https://www.facebook.com/cielomuyot/posts/905033959510865"></fb:comments>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code, otherwise it will be difficult to help. And, it's likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: Please put the code in the question, not in the comments! Nobody can read this...

Comment: So, what exactly doesn't work? I see one comment when I test this: http://jsfiddle.net/LZ9UE/

Comment: That's the comment that I submitted using that code (it's not a comment in the post). What I want to do is to get all the comments from the facebook post itself. Is it possible?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/comments if you know the `post_id`

Comment: I can't make it work. lol. I always get the error "Unknown path components: /903985589615702" (which is the post id)
Edit: I tried it using this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=posts%2F903985589615702&version=v2.0) btw

Comment: That's not a post_id. It also doesn't seem to be public, so no one can see ist to test

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The Comments Plugin is completely unrelated to Facebook posts. The href parameter is more or less just an id to get different comment plugins on one page.

That means, it does not make any sense to use a facebook.com URL as href parameter, always use the URL where you implement it (with a get parameter if you need more than one Comment Plugins on one page).

Comment: So, you mean the Facebook comments in [9gag.tv](http://9gag.tv/p/a5y38M/a-cat-s-guide-to-loving-a-human-cole-the-black-cat-marmalade) is not really from Facebook? xD I mean, it's like they're just really posting from another page but the profile being used is their Facebook profile?

Comment: @luschn is correct. If you want the comments from Facebook posts, use the Graph API

Comment: yes, and yes :) - you can get the facebook comments with the graph api, although they are still not connected in any way to the comments plugin.

Comment: Alright, I managed to get the comments using the Graph API Explorer. But I still have no idea how I can put it into PHP. Lol. I'll try to find solutions for this. Thank you very much guys! :)

Comment: i recently wrote a tutorial for the php sdk, may be interesting for you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/